# Pandas Resampler Key Error

Tags: python, pandas

My first ever question on StackOverflow. Until now I've always been able to find answers to my questions with a search. Hopefully not embarrassing myself by asking a duplicate question.

I am resampling a pandas dataframe. I then want to loop through the dataframes in the resampler object to extract some information.

However, when I use the keys returned by the resampler.groups.keys() I get a key error when there is no data for that week. This seems inconsistent to me. I would have expected to get an empty dataframe or for the keys() method or to not get a key for that week's group at all.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('debug.csv', index_col = 'DATETIME', parse_dates=True)

by_week = df.resample('W-SUN')
by_week.groups
```

Gives:

```
{Timestamp('2017-02-26 00:00:00', offset='W-SUN'): 1,
 Timestamp('2017-03-05 00:00:00', offset='W-SUN'): 1,
 Timestamp('2017-03-12 00:00:00', offset='W-SUN'): 1,
 Timestamp('2017-03-19 00:00:00', offset='W-SUN'): 8}
```

Then sum just to show there is no data in the middle two weeks:

```
print by_week.sum()

                   ID    DATA
DATETIME                     
2017-02-26  1020754.0    74.0
2017-03-05        NaN     NaN
2017-03-12        NaN     NaN
2017-03-19  7151408.0  2526.0
```

Show keys for resampler groups:

```
for key in sorted(by_week.groups.keys(), reverse=True):
    print key

2017-03-19 00:00:00
2017-03-12 00:00:00
2017-03-05 00:00:00
2017-02-26 00:00:00
```

Try to do something for each group dataframe. First week is fine, but the second week craps out. Why is the keys() method returning an invalid key?

```
for key in sorted(by_week.groups.keys(), reverse=True):
    df = by_week.get_group(key)
    print df.head()

                              ID  DATA
DATETIME                              
2017-03-18 22:41:10.859  1021626   384
2017-03-18 23:45:18.773  1021627   375
2017-03-18 23:45:35.309  1021628   359
2017-03-18 23:46:45.303  1021629   188
2017-03-19 01:02:23.554  1021633   373


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a57723281f49> in <module>()
      1 for key in sorted(by_week.groups.keys(), reverse=True):
----> 2     df = by_week.get_group(key)
      3     print df.head()

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in get_group(self, name, obj)
    585         inds = self._get_index(name)
    586         if not len(inds):
--> 587             raise KeyError(name)
    588 
    589         return obj.take(inds, axis=self.axis, convert=False)

KeyError: Timestamp('2017-03-12 00:00:00', offset='W-SUN')
```

My workaround below. Also appreciate any feedback on if there is a more appropriate way to handle this. This skips the middle two weeks without data. Is there a fundamentally better way to iterate over each week's data?

```
for key in sorted(by_week.groups.keys(), reverse=True):
    try:
        df = by_week.get_group(key)
    except:
        continue
    print df.head()

                              ID  DATA
DATETIME                              
2017-03-18 22:41:10.859  1021626   384
2017-03-18 23:45:18.773  1021627   375
2017-03-18 23:45:35.309  1021628   359
2017-03-18 23:46:45.303  1021629   188
2017-03-19 01:02:23.554  1021633   373
                              ID  DATA
DATETIME                              
2017-02-21 13:42:01.133  1020754    74
```

Edit/Update:
To address response below about using the built in iterator. My original code did use the built in iterator but I got this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('debug.csv', index_col = 'DATETIME', parse_dates=True)
by_week = df.resample('W-SUN')

for key, df in by_week:
    print df.head()
```

gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug_sampler.py", line 10, in <module>
    for key, df in by_week:
  File "<redacted path>/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 600, in __iter__
    return self.grouper.get_iterator(self.obj, axis=self.axis)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_iterator'
```

Interestingly, if I use groupby instead, it's fine. But I hate to give up the convenience of the resample method (e.g. resampling by week ending on an aribtrary day).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('debug.csv', index_col = 'DATETIME', parse_dates=True)

by_week_groupby = df.groupby(lambda x: x.week)

for key, df in by_week_groupby:
    print df.head()
```

gives:

```
                              ID  DATA
DATETIME                              
2017-02-21 13:42:01.133  1020754    74
                              ID  DATA
DATETIME                              
2017-03-19 17:01:01.352  1021625   428
2017-03-18 22:41:10.859  1021626   384
2017-03-18 23:45:18.773  1021627   375
2017-03-18 23:45:35.309  1021628   359
2017-03-18 23:46:45.303  1021629   188
```

The installed version of pandas:

```
print pd.__version__
0.18.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't force your own iteration through the `groupby` object when pandas has one already (though not obvious)

```
for key, df in byweek:
    print(df.head())
```

Comment: Have to retract my now deleted comment. I mis-remembered the issue. This worked fine when I used locally in Jupyter iPython notebook on my Mac. But when I used it in a flat .py file run from command line on a virtual machine, I got this.

Comment: return self.grouper.get_iterator(self.obj, axis=self.axis)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_iterator'
\n That's why I moved to my own iteration. I never tracked down why the built in iterator worked on my local machine but not on the virtual machine.

Comment: Sorry. One more comment. On the virtual machine, the built in iterator did work on a "regular" groupby object, but not on one generated by the resample method. I thought that was also odd.